# Sphinx (via SphinxQL) match without asterisk, but not with asterisk

Tags: search-engine, sphinx, wildcard

I have an index in Sphinx, one of the words in this index is an article number. In this case `04.007.00964`.
When I query my index like this:

`SELECT * FROM myIndex WHERE MATCH('04.007.00964')`

I have one result, this is as expected.
However, when I query it like this:

`SELECT * FROM myIndex WHERE MATCH('*04.007.00964*')`

I have zero results.

My index configuration is:

```
index myIndex
{
    source          = myIndex
    path            = D:\Tools\Sphinx\data\myIndex
    morphology      = none
    min_word_len    = 3
    min_prefix_len  = 0
    min_infix_len   = 2
    enable_star     = 1
}
```

I'm using v2.0.4-release

What am I doing wrong, or what dont I understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of

```
min_word_len    = 3
```

The first query will be effectivly:

```
SELECT * FROM myIndex WHERE MATCH('007 00964')
```

So short words are ignored. (indexing and querying)

Edit to add: And "." is not in the default charset_table, which is why its used as a seperator.

However "*04" is not stripped, because it 3 chars,

but then there is nothing to match, because "04" will not be in the index (its shorter than the min_word_len)

... so its a unfortunate combination of word and infix lengths. Can easily fix it by making min_word_len = 2

Edit to add: or adding '.' to charset tables, so that its no longer used to separate words, therefore the whole article number is used - and is longer than both min_word_len and min_infix_len)

Comment: But the 04.007.00964 should be seen as one word, as this is my article number

Comment: It wont be. the "." is a separator. It can be changed with charset_tables - you don't have one in your configuration, so you using the default table, which has "." as a separator.

Comment: Thanks this works, I've added the '.' to the charset_table. Maybe you could edit your answer and I can mark it as the answer.